# APN is not specified?

Tags: blackberry

iam creating httpConnection ,but when run the application it gives following exception ?

java.io.IOException
APN is not specified ?

Comment: it says Access Point is not specified ,

Comment: What type of connection are you using ? If possible post some code also.

Answer (score 4):

I think the See the Developer Knowledge Base article: link can solve your problem
http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0

also see this sample code

```
private static String getConnectionString(){
    String connectionString="";
    if(WLANInfo.getWLANState()==WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED){
        connectionString="?;interface=wifi";
    }

    else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS){
         connectionString = "?;&deviceside=false";
    }
    else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)==CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT){
        String carrierUid=getCarrierBIBSUid();
        if(carrierUid == null) {
            connectionString = "?;deviceside=true";
        }
        else{
            connectionString = "?;deviceside=false?;connectionUID="+carrierUid + "?;ConnectionType=mds-public";
        }               
    }
    else if(CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) {          
            }
        return connectionString;
    }
```

Comment: or you can manually set the Apn name, go to Options>Advanced Option>TCP/IP and enter the service provider's apn.it may get by googling or contact your network provider

Comment: Also see http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-API/ta-p/538863 and the ConnectionFactory class.

Answer (score 0):

More to the point,

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-get-APN-Settings/td-p/1704995

It is not completely possible to put the APN settings in your url eg. there is no way to get the username and password.