# Blackberry check internet connection on device

Tags: blackberry, internet-connection

How do I check if the Internet connection is ON or OFF on a device?

Answer (score 4):

You better check using

```
CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT);
```

The CoverageInfo class provides some more types of coverage to check for. See http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CoverageInfo.html

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no direct way.
You just request for a server,if there is there is no internet not avilable at that time an exception is thrown, you catch it display an alert to the user.
Some thing like below:

```
try {
// request http
}
catch(IOException e) {  
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Dialog.alert("No Internet Connectivity");   
                    //System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: thanx.jisson .but you have any other idea for check connection . like  CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) .

Comment: you can refer the stack overflow link and its answer,still doubt free to ask.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620594/apn-is-not-specified/5621186#5621186

Comment: Also note the I put  "?"s in the function (in the above link),you can avoid it.

Comment: I never used CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient..Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Call this method, if it returns true then you've got connection. It checks to ensure you have enough battery for internet connection, your 3G or wireless is turned on and then you have enough signal.

```
public synchronized static boolean checkConnection() {  
        boolean returnVal = true;

    if (DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel() < 6) {
        returnVal = false;
    }
    else if (RadioInfo.getState() == RadioInfo.STATE_OFF) {
        returnVal = false;
    }
    else if (RadioInfo.getSignalLevel() == RadioInfo.LEVEL_NO_COVERAGE) {       
        returnVal = false;
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use in my application, and it works just fine:

```
protected static boolean isOutOfServiceRange() {
    return !RadioInfo.isDataServiceOperational();
}
```